# Why do I get "nothing to commit, working tree clean" after a merge request?

Tags: git, gitlab

Why does git status in branch develoment after a merge request on origin develoment in gitlab tell me "`nothing to commit, working tree clean`" but when I do a git pull in branch development it fetches the latest status. I can't imagine that this is a bug. Git and Gitlab are too ingenious for that. What am I getting wrong?

```bash
git checkout development
git status

On branch development
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/development'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**git pull**

```bash
remote: Enumerating objects: 30, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (30/30), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), 1.56 KiB | 177.00 KiB/s, done.

Updating ec27aa4..75941c3
Fast-forward
 .env                           |  1 +
 .env.node                      |  3 ++-
...
 8 files changed, 25 insertions(+), 12 deletions(-)
```

Comment: It sounds like you just don't understand what `git status` reports and what `git pull` means?

Comment: `git checkout development` executed in local copy of repository, so git does not know about updates in gitlab before you run a command to communicate with. Try `git fetch` to get information about remote state before `git checkout ...`

Comment: @matt You are probably right. Can you give me a short explanation, please?

Comment: @MaxPattern That would be my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: @matt Thx matt for the link. I hope i can read tonight :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I getting wrong?

`git status` doesn't know about updates to remote branches; it just looks at the current state of your local repo. If you were to run `git fetch`, git would download the remote changes. If you then run `git status`, it'll tell you that your local branch is behind.

`git pull` is essentially a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`, so running it automatically gets the remote changes.